# GTK+ и организация строк

Tags: c, windows, utf-8, gtk+

Я совсем запутался с тем, как именно **GTK+** работает со строками.

Вопросы такие:

1) **gtk_label_set_text()** просит **utf-8** строку? То есть, исходники программы должны быть в **utf-8**? А если нет?

2) Могут ли возникнуть проблемы при использовании **printf() / fprintf() / sprintf()** со строками **utf-8**?

3) Везде пишут, что **gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()** возвращает имя выбранного файла в **utf-8** и эту строку можно сразу *скармливать* функции **fopen()**...

Но в **Windows 10** при использовании **MinGW w64** это не так. И это очень напрягает, потому что я вообще не понимаю, где и какие могут возникнуть проблемы, пока с ними не столкнусь. И это очень мешает планированию.

4) Являются ли **utf-8** строки, полученные через **g_convert()**, нультерминированными? И если да, то нультерминатор - однобайтовый ноль?

Comment: для gtk_label_set_text подойдёт обычный char, по коду она  распознает русский шрифт.

Comment: Каким образом? Ведь представление расширенных кодов в однобайтовых символах зависит от настроек локали.

Comment: Я в линуксе в обычном char пишу русский текст и всё нормально. Да локаль, но она utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Судя по [докам](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html), GTK+ всюду работает с utf8:

> Glib uses UTF-8 for its strings, and GUI toolkits like GTK+ that use GLib do the same thing.

Исходники программы могут быть в любой кодировке, но строки надо конвертировать в utf-8 перед тем, как передавать их в gtk.

3) Про `gtk_file_chooser_get_filename()` сказано, что она возвращает строку в "сырой" кодировке, которую понимает файловая система, а не в utf-8. Но в описании функции [`g_filename_to_utf8()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html#g-filename-to-utf8) сказано, что для Windows, в качестве кодировки имени файлов, всегда используется utf-8 (т.е. функции `g_filename_to_utf8` и `g_filename_from_utf8`, по сути, никаких преобразований не совершают). Соответственно, вам надо перекодировать строку для передачи её в `fopen`.

4) Да, и в качестве нуля [там записывается целых 4 байта](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/ec4da774e5cbcd64ccd048bd2431ec9bbdd1f8e7/glib/gconvert.c#L166):

> We try to terminate strings in unknown charsets with this many zero bytes
>   to ensure that multibyte strings really are nul-terminated when we return
>   them from g_convert() and friends.
>   `#define NUL_TERMINATOR_LENGTH 4`

Comment: Я не очень понял третий пункт. Файловая система Windows использует UTF-16LE. GTK использует UTF-8, а стандартный fopen() просит ascii.

Comment: Сперва для решения проблемы я попробовал использовать преобразование UTF-8 -> CP1251, но это решение имеет тот недостаток, что не позволит открыть файлы, в именах которых есть символы, которые нельзя отобразить в CP1251. Мне это решение не очень нравится, хотя им можно было бы пользоваться в подавляющем большинстве ситуаций.

Comment: Я думал над использованием функции _wfopen() или CreateFileW(). Они просят строку в UTF-16LЕ и, следовательно, позволят открыть файл с любыми символами юникода... Но процесс конвертации UTF-8->UTF-16LE вызывает у меня трудности, возможно я что-то делаю не так с g_convert(). Хотелось бы использовать _wfopen(), эта функция и ее родственные более удобны, чем работа с Win API. Подскажите, как можно преобразовать имя файла из UTF-8 в UTF-16LE (wchar_t) и каковы аналоги fseek()/ftell()/fclose() при использовании _wfopen().

Comment: @Максим О том, как конвертировать utf8 в utf16, вам наверняка подскажут в другом вопросе/ответе. Одна проблема - один вопрос.